# FASM HelloWorld .exe program

Tags: assembly, exe, fasm

I tried to write my first .exe program on FASM. It works ok when I use org 100h, but I want to compile .exe file. When I replaced first line with "format PE GUI 4.0" and tried to compile it the error occured: "value out of range" (line: mov dx,msg).

```
ORG 100h      ;format PE GUI 4.0

mov dx,msg
mov ah,9h
int 21h

mov ah,10h
int 16h

int 21h

msg db "Hello World!$"
```

How should I change the source code?

----------------------------------------------
The answer is:

```
format mz
org 100h

mov edx,msg
mov ah,9h
int 21h

mov ah,10h
int 16h

mov ax,$4c01
int 21h

msg db "Hello World!$"
```

Comment: I'm no expert in fasm, but have you tried `movb`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first version is in COM format. It is a 16-bit real mode FLAT model.
Your second version is in DOS MZ format. It is a 16-bit real mode SEGMENTED model.

Segmented model uses "segments" to describe your DS (segment) and DX (offset). So firstly you need to define segments for your data and code, and secondly you need to point correctly where is your data segment and what is your offset before you can use the int 21h, function 9.

**int 21h, function 9 needs a DS:DX to be setup correctly in segmented model, to print a null terminated string**

```
format MZ
entry .code:start
segment .code
start:
mov ax, .data ; put data segment into ax
mov ds, ax    ; there, I setup the DS for you
mov dx, msg   ; now I give you the offset in DX. DS:DX now completed.
mov ah, 9h
int 21h
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
segment .data
msg db 'Hello World', '$'
```

Hope this helps some FASM newbies out there.

Comment: A $-terminated string, I'd say?

Answer (score 2):

If you want DOS exe, you need **format mz**.

Comment: thanks! format mz help me to compile program, but the output is: "[many strange characters]Hello World!". It seems like address of msg is not correct

Comment: if the beginning of the file is: format mz    org 100h    mov dx,msg... I get a NTVDM.exe crash. If the beginnig of the file is: format mz   mov dx,msg... I get a incorrect output.

Comment: Oh no. I get MTVDM.exe unstable crash in both cases (with or without org100h). At least if I kept 100h the output is correct.

Comment: You're not setting the int 21h function. Try with **org 100h** and **mov     ax,$4c01    int     $21h**

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try using `lea` instead (i.e., `lea dx, msg`); this takes the offset of the operand, and may be better suited to what you're wanting...

Comment: What have you written? lea should be picked up as an instruction not an operand...

Comment: Does FASM support the MASM/TASM "mov dx, offset msg" style?  Unless you need a special feature of lea, it's best to avoid it.  It's slower on older processors (I believe all the new ones have extra hardware to make it fast though).