# error: value out of range in FASM x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

why am I getting `error: value out of range.` in the following code?

```
mov eax,dword ptr "abcdlol$"
```

I want to put the address of `"abcdlol"` into `eax` register but looks like isn't this value that FASM is copying into `eax`.

An example In C code: `int *p="lol";`

How to fix this? Is this an assembler's limitation?

Comment: Assembly language is very primitive, almost as primitive as individual instructions. `mov eax,dword ptr "abcdlol$"` (supposing for the moment it's correct and meaningful) and `int *p="lol";` are asking to do at least some two things: allocate space for data and write the data there and get the address of that data into a register or a variable. Not a single instruction or assembly language directive can do all that. You have to further break things down into data definitions/declarations and code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It FASM syntax it should be:

```
mov eax,my_string
my_string db "abcdlol$"
```

You can also use `lea`:

```
lea eax,[my_string]
my_string db "abcdlol$"
```

Whether to use ASCIIZ string (terminated with 0) or some other terminator depends on what you are going to do with the string. It seems that you are using `$` as string terminator, that is used by DOS print string function. Check that `$` is the right string terminator for the OS API functions you are going to use (if any). For example `printf` requires zero-terminated (ASCIIZ) strings.

See [FASM HelloWorld .exe program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174565/fasm-helloworld-exe-program) see an example of FASM syntax.

`dword ptr` and the like are needed only when addressing the memory. `mov eax,abcdlol` is just a `mov eax,immed32`. Processor does not worry whether you're you're going to use the value stored in `eax` as a number or as a pointer.

Comment: Is `abcdlol` a label in your example? I really want to put into eax the string's address.

Comment: Yes, `abcdlol` is a label, otherwise you couldn't refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
mystring  db  "abcdlol", 0
mov eax,mystring
```

Answer (score 0):

Back to basics:

EAX can store only 4 bytes. "abcdlol$" is 8 bytes. So instead of putting the value directly, you should put the address of it into EAX as suggested by other posters. But if you insist, use two registers:

```
mov eax,"abcd" ;4 bytes
mov ebx,"lol$" ;4 bytes
```

or in 64-bit,

```
mov rax,"abcdlol$"
```

You should tell the difference between passing immediate values and passing addresses to the registers.